# how to decode html elements in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with Angular 2 and C#, SQL Server (database). I have a scenario where some HTML string is coming from database which contains the HTML tags or special characters like- (> , < & etc).

So when it's coming from database the special character's are coming in encoded format. But I wanted to decode it in it's actual content in TypeScript file. Below is the example of my original string-

```
 if > 10
```

And it's showing in UI as below-

```
if  &gt; 10
```

I am using below code in HTML-

```
<div class="bold-text">{{vm.Name}}</div>
```

Can anyone suggest how we can decode it in TypeScript or Angular 2 .

Comment: try <div [innerHTML]="vm.Name"></div>

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive

```
 <p ng-bind-html="vm.Name"></p>
```

Comment: @Saneetharan, it's working like this <p ng-bind-html="vm.Name | renderHTML"></p>

Comment: But I am not sure what is the diff between ng-bind-html and ng-bind-html | renderHTML ?

Comment: what do you mean